# Access a vector or an array from another file in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, cmake

I'm trying to access the elements of an array/vector from another file (pattern.cpp here). According to this discussion (http://cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/183828/) I should do

```
//pattern.cpp
namespace myprogram {
void Pattern::FromReal()
{
    extern std::vector<double> real_data;
    for (auto it=real_data.begin(); it !=real_data.end(); it++)
      std::cout<<" my vector "<< *it <<" ";
 }
}
and the vector is here
//RealData.cpp
#include <vector>
std::vector<double> real_data{ 0., 0., 1.46, 1.51, 1.55, 1.58, 1.45, 1.48, 1.54, 1.54, 1.60, 1.56};
```

When I compile I get this error

```
<directory>/x86_64/Gcc/gcc620_x86_64_slc6/6.2.0/x86_64-slc6/include/c++/6.2.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:770: undefined reference to `myprogram::real_data'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And I use CMake and RealData.cpp is already added to CMakeList. What is wrong here? What should I change?

Comment: Could you show your CMakeList as well? Are you including a header file or the cpp file to `pattern.cpp`?

Comment: @mrq1901 Check out the working example given in my answer. Just create(if not already) a realdata.h file which have the extern for the `real_data` vector. Then you can just include this header in  pattern.cpp and wherever you want  this `real_data` vector like in main.cpp .

Comment: As you can see from the error message, it refers to `myprogram::real_data`: a definition of the `real_data` in the **namespace** `myprogram`. Your `RealData.cpp` file defines `real_data` **outside of any namespace**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://onlinegdb.com/2u3bZqPAZ) is the working example. Just create(if not already) a realdata.h file which have the `extern` for the `real_data` vector. Then you can just include this header in pattern.cpp and wherever you want this `real_data` vector like in main.cpp .

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "pattern.h"
#include "realdata.h"

extern std::vector<double> real_data;
int main()
{
    
    std::cout<<"Size of vector from other file is: "<<real_data.size()<<std::endl;
    myprogram::Pattern obj;
    obj.FromReal();
    return 0;
}
```

**pattern.h**

```
 #ifndef PATTERN_H
#define PATTERN_H
namespace myprogram {
    
    class Pattern 
    {
        
    public:
        void FromReal();
    };
}
#endif
```

**pattern.cpp**

```
#include "pattern.h"
#include "realdata.h"
#include <iostream>
namespace myprogram{
void Pattern::FromReal()
        {
    
            for (auto it=real_data.begin(); it !=real_data.end(); it++)
            std::cout<<" my vector "<< *it <<" "<<std::endl;
        }
        
}
```

**realdata.h**

```
#ifndef REALDATA_H
#define REALDATA_H
#include<vector>
extern std::vector<double> real_data;
#endif
```

**realdata.cpp**

```
#include "realdata.h"
std::vector<double> real_data{ 0., 0., 1.46, 1.51, 1.55, 1.58, 1.45, 1.48, 1.54, 1.54, 1.60, 1.56};
```

Also don't forget to use **header guards**